# send image to other app via intent from sd card

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am trying to send an image to other app via intent...I am sending image from internal storage but I can't share it from my sd card...how can I share it from sd card..?

Here is my code:

```
public void shareMultipleImages(View v) {
    String imagePath1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "SD card/fb images/" + "gujju.jpg";
    String imagePath2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "SD card/fb images/" + "zindgi.jpg";
    // Multiple Images' file objects
    File image1FileToShare = new File(imagePath1);
    File image2FileToShare = new File(imagePath2);
    // Get URI of Image's location
    Uri image1URI = Uri.fromFile(image1FileToShare);
    Uri image2URI = Uri.fromFile(image2FileToShare);
    ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    imageUris.add(image1URI); // Add your image URIs here
    imageUris.add(image2URI); // Add your image URIs here
    // Set the action to be performed i.e 'Send Multiple Data'
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    // Add the URIs holding a stream of data 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
    // Set the type of data i.e 'image/* which means image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg etc.,'
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    // Launches the activity; Open 'Gallery' if you set it as default app to handle Image
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Comment: You can do it by using ContentProvider.

Comment: how can i use it..? can u plz give me code..? i am new to android

Comment: Which version are you using for testing?

Comment: If 6.0 or above ask for run-time permission to access SD card.

Comment: Try this.....http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/share-image-in-android/

Comment: `trying to send an image to other app via intent..`. It looks as if you only want to send a path to an image to another application. Please be clear!

Comment: `trying to send an image to other app via intent..`. It looks if you try for two image uri's. But the way you tried will not work.

Comment: Can you send one image uri? If yes then start showing that code. And tell your story!

Comment: no...i want to send image